# Turn off Notifications for Facebook Comments Plugin

Tags: facebook, notifications

We've implemented the Facebook Comments box on our website. I'm set up as a moderator, which means I receive a Facebook notification anytime anyone posts a comment via the comments box.

Happy to say we receive much engagement on our sites, but unfortunately this means I receive a notification almost every other minute. Do we know if there's a way to turn this notification feature off? At least for myself and not other moderators?  I'd really just like to be alerted of activity on my own personal Facebook profile, rather than my website

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I have same problem with you, how do you solve your problem?

Answer (score 1):

There doesn't seem to be a way to turn them off (I've searched extensively). However, you can create a separate Facebook account – "Grace Moderator", or something like that – and set that as the moderator instead of your main account. Then you won't get the notifications in your main account.